# binomial distribution with replacing the opposite color of the items.

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm not sure which discrete probability distribution to use for this kind of problem.

We are given two sets of balls **n** blue and **m** red. This is very similar to a binomial distribution except that every time that when drawing a ball at random, when a blue ball is drawn, 1 blue is taken out of the urn and 1 red ball is added to the urn. When a red ball is drawn the game ends.

What distribution would I use for the formula for $P \{X=k\}$ be where X is the number of blue balls drawn before the first red one is drawn?

Comment: Everytime a blue ball is taken out a red one is added or a red ball is added no matter what colour ball is taken out?

Comment: every time a blue ball is picked, a blue one is taken out and a red one is added.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the identities
$$P[X\geqslant k+1]=\frac{n}{n+m}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n-1+m+1}\cdots\frac{n-k}{n-k+m+k}$$
and
$$
P[X=k]=P[X\geqslant k]-P[X\geqslant k+1].
$$